# Spring Cloud Stream - Concurrency

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Using Spring Cloud Stream Version Chelsea.SR2, with RabbitMQ as message broker. To have multiple consumers we are using the property concurrency (The concurrency of the inbound consumer).
If we set concurrency as 50. It is starting with 1 and slowly it is increasing the consumers count. Is there any possible solution to start initial consumer Count with higher number instead of one to increase the consumer performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you show your configuration? I just tested it and it worked exactly as expected...

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=10
```

with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So48953227Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48953227Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {

    }

}
```

and

[image]

immediately, without sending any messages